# MySQL Connection String settings

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm using the following options in my connection string:

```
autoReconnect true  
autoReconnectForPools true  
cacheCallableStmts true  
cachePrepStmts true  
useCompression true  
useSSL true  
requireSSL true  
paranoid true  
useLocalTransactionState true  
characterEncoding UTF8  
useServerPrepStmts true  
zeroDateTimeBehavior CONVERT_TO_NULL  
databaseName AUDIT  
serverName sqlsrv.lan  
portNumber 3306
```

Is this ok or should there be things added/removed? I'm looking for the best possible performance

Comment: If "autoRecommect is passed to MySQL, that is unsafe.  If a crash occurs in the middle of a transaction, the first part is lost, but the rest runs without it.